# TypeScript Type Generics not properly infering type

Tags: typescript

Consider the following code:

```
interface Entity<T extends DataFetcherImp> {
  name: string,
  fetcher: () => T
}

type UUID = string;

declare abstract class DataFetcherImp {
  public static fetch(id: UUID);
}

class TestFetcher implements DataFetcherImp {
  public static async fetch(id: UUID): Promise<TestFetcher> {
    return new TestFetcher(id);
  }

  constructor(private id: UUID) {
    // perform some io
  }
}

class OtherTestFetcher implements DataFetcherImp {
  public static async fetch(id: UUID): Promise<OtherTestFetcher> {
    return new OtherTestFetcher(id);
  }

  constructor(private id: UUID) {
    // perform some other io
  }
}

class DataFetcher_Broken {
  public async getData<T extends DataFetcherImp>(entity: Entity<T>, id: UUID): Promise<T> {
    return await entity.fetcher().fetch(id); // [2339] Property 'fetch' does not exist on type 'T'.
  }
}

class DataFetcher_Working {

  public async getData(entity: Entity<typeof TestFetcher>, id: UUID): Promise<TestFetcher>;
  public async getData(entity: Entity<typeof OtherTestFetcher>, id: UUID): Promise<OtherTestFetcher>;
  public async getData(entity: Entity<typeof TestFetcher | typeof OtherTestFetcher>, id: UUID): Promise<TestFetcher | OtherTestFetcher> {
    return await entity.fetcher().fetch(id);
  }
}
```

The class `DataFetcher_Broken` should in my understanding be working. But `tsc` outputs an error: `[2339] Property 'fetch' does not exist on type 'T'.` It seems like the compiler wants a *non-static* method fetch to exist on the type T.
But the method has to be static, since a library is used, which only provides static methods on a generic abstract class.

As you can see the class `DataFetcher_Working` does the job, but then there is another problem. How can the class be extended to work with other classes which implement the `DataFetcherImp` abstraction? Also with classes we have no control over?
Let's assume some user of the `DataFetcher` utility class creates a class `YetAnotherFetcher`. This class then can not be used with the `DataFetcher_Working` without modifying the method signature. So this method can not be included in a library.

```
const df = new DataFetcher_Working();
df.getData({
    name: 'yaf',
    fetcher: () => YetAnotherFetcher // [2322] Type 'typeof YetAnotherFetcher' is not assignable to type 'typeof OtherTestFetcher'.  Types of property 'fetch' are incompatible.    Type '(id: string) => Promise<YetAnotherFetcher>' is not assignable to type '(id: string) => Promise<OtherTestFetcher>'.      Type 'Promise<YetAnotherFetcher>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<OtherTestFetcher>'.        Type 'YetAnotherFetcher' is not assignable to type 'OtherTestFetcher'.          Types have separate declarations of a private property 'id'.
}, 'd6413b62-5bc7-4670-a28e-d14c822d1dd8');
```

So the generic way as in `DataFetcher_Broken` is the only way to go.

Following modifications allready tried but not working:

1.

```
class DataFetcher_Broken {
  public async getData<T extends DataFetcherImp>(entity: Entity<T>, id: UUID): Promise<T> {
    return await (entity.fetcher() as any as typeof DataFetcherImp).fetch(id);
  }
}
```

this change allows for

```
const df = new DataFetcher_Broken();
df.getData({ name: 'completeDesaster', fetcher: () => Object }, 'd6413b62-5bc7-4670-a28e-d14c822d1dd8');
```

but `Object` has no static method `fetch`.

2.

```
class DataFetcher_Broken {
  public async getData<T extends DataFetcherImp>(entity: Entity<T>, id: UUID): Promise<T> {
    return await (entity.fetcher() as DataFetcherImp).fetch(id); // [2576] Property 'fetch' is a static member of type 'DataFetcherImp'
  }
}
```

3.

```
interface Entity<T extends DataFetcherImp> {
  name: string,
  fetcher: () => typeof DataFetcherImp
}
```

this change would kinda make sense, but then the type `T` on the entity is not anymore enforced for the `fetcher` property and it yields yet another error:

```
const df = new DataFetcher_Broken();
df.getData({ name: 'willNotCompile', fetcher: () => TestFetcher }, 'd6413b62-5bc7-4670-a28e-d14c822d1dd8'); // [2322] Type 'typeof TestFetcher' is not assignable to type 'typeof DataFetcherImp'.
```

Any suggestions, how to get this working?

[TS Playground: minimal example.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20Entity%3CT%20extends%20DataFetcherImp%3CT%3E%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20name%3A%20string%2C%0A%20%20fetcher%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20T%0A%7D%0A%0Atype%20UUID%20%3D%20string%3B%0A%0Adeclare%20abstract%20class%20DataFetcherImp%3CT%20extends%20DataFetcherImp%3CT%3E%3E%20extends%20Object%20%7B%0A%20%20static%20fetch%3CT%20extends%20DataFetcherImp%3CT%3E%3E(this%3A%20(new%20()%20%3D%3E%20T)%2C%20id%3A%20UUID)%3A%20Promise%3CT%3E%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20TestFetcher%20extends%20DataFetcherImp%3CTestFetcher%3E%20%7B%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20DataFetcher%20%7B%0A%20%20public%20async%20getData%3CT%20extends%20typeof%20DataFetcherImp%3E(entity%3A%20Entity%3CT%3E%2C%20id%3A%20UUID)%3A%20Promise%3CT%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20await%20entity.fetcher().fetch(id)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20const%20df%20%3D%20new%20DataFetcher()%3B%0A%20%20df.getData(%7B%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20'completeDesaster'%2C%0A%20%20%20%20fetcher%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20TestFetcher%0A%20%20%7D%2C%20'd6413b62-5bc7-4670-a28e-d14c822d1dd8')%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Amain()%3B) (The part where the static functions get copied to the prototype of the `TestFetcher` are omitted)

Answer (score 0):

Because `fetch` is static, it actually won't exist on an instance of `DataFetcherImp`, but only on a `typeof DataFetcherImp`.

Here is the change that removes the error (`T extends typeof DataFetcherImp`):

```
class DataFetcher_Broken {
  public async getData<T extends typeof DataFetcherImp>(entity: Entity<T>, id: UUID): Promise<T> {
    return await entity.fetcher().fetch(id);
  }
}
```

Comment: This gives now another problem: `[2684] The 'this' context of type 'T' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'new () => DataFetcherImp<DataFetcherImp<any>>'.
  Type 'typeof DataFetcherImp' is not assignable to type 'new () => DataFetcherImp<DataFetcherImp<any>>'.
    Cannot assign an abstract constructor type to a non-abstract constructor type.` (The type of `DataFetcherImp` is actually `declare abstract class DataFetcherImp<T extends DataFetcherImp<T>> extends SomethingElse`)

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example that shows the error? Happy to look at a TypeScript Playground link.